# Is it possible to listen for join and leave events on a room?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I want to do something like:

```
var room = io.sockets.in('some super awesome room');
room.on('join', function () {
    /* stuff */
});
room.on('leave', function () {
    /* stuff */
});
```

This doesn't seem to work. Is it possible?

To illustrate the desired behavior:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.join('some super awesome room'); // should fire the above 'join' event
});
```

Comment: For when you join/leave, or for when someone else does?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. I have a "room" and I want to know when _any_ socket joins or leaves it.

Comment: Sockets don't join or leave rooms.  Clients join or leave rooms.  I take it you're interested in clients (that aren't you), then?

Comment: I don't think you understand the question. There is no "me"... this is server-side code. According to the [socket.io docs](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io), sockets do join and leave rooms:

`var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.join('justin bieber fans');
  socket.broadcast.to('justin bieber fans').emit('new fan');
  io.sockets.in('rammstein fans').emit('new non-fan');
});`

Comment: Ahh.  So the "room" is a low-level thing, kinda like a multicast group, rather than a chat room.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Socket.IO, a "room" is really just a namespace, something to help you filter your giant bag of sockets down to a smaller bag of sockets. Calling `io.sockets.in('room').on('something')` will cause the event handler to fire for *every* socket in the room when the event fires. If that's what you want, something like this should do the trick:

```
var room = io.sockets.in('some super awesome room');
room.on('join', function() {
  console.log("Someone joined the room.");
});
room.on('leave', function() {
  console.log("Someone left the room.");
});

socket.join('some super awesome room');
socket.broadcast.to('some super awesome room').emit('join');

setTimeout(function() {
  socket.leave('some super awesome room');
  io.sockets.in('some super awesome room').emit('leave');
}, 10 * 1000);
```

Important to note is that you'd get the same effect if you (1) got a list of all sockets in a room and (2) iterated over them, calling `emit('join')` on each. Thus, you should make sure that your event name is specific enough that you won't accidentally emit it outside the "namespace" of a room.

If you only want to emit/consume a *single* event when a socket joins or leaves a room, you'll need to write that yourself, as, again, a room isn't a "thing" as much as it's a "filter".

Comment: `a room isn't a "thing" as much as it's a "filter"` -- this is what I was worried about (I wish socket.io had better docs). I guess I'll have to write my own version of rooms... Thanks!

Comment: I have question about parameters for `join` handler - http://stackoverflow.com/q/16969463/37759

Answer (score 8):

I understand this question is old, but for anyone that stumbles upon this via a google search, this is how I'm approaching it.

Joining a room is something that is pretty easy to account for, even though there aren't native events for joining or leaving a room.

```
/* client.js */
var socket = io();
socket.on('connect', function () {
    // Join a room
    socket.emit('joinRoom', "random-room");
});
```

And for the server-side

```
/* server.js */
// This will have the socket join the room and then broadcast 
// to all sockets in the room that someone has joined
socket.on("joinRoom", function (roomName) {
    socket.join(roomName);
    io.sockets.in(roomName).emit('message','Someone joined the room');
}

// This will have the rooms the current socket is a member of
// the "disconnect" event is after tear-down, so socket.rooms would already be empty
// so we're using disconnecting, which is before tear-down of sockets
socket.on("disconnecting", function () {
    var rooms = socket.rooms;
    console.log(rooms);
    // You can loop through your rooms and emit an action here of leaving
});
```

Where it gets a bit trickier is when they disconnect, but luckily a `disconnecting` event was added that happens before the tear down of sockets in the room. In the example above, if the event was `disconnect` then the rooms would be empty, but `disconnecting` will have all rooms that they belong to. For our example, you'll have two rooms that the socket will be a part of, the `Socket#id` and `random-room`

I hope this points someone else in the right direction from my research and testing.

Comment: Thx so much, this is exactly what I was looking for! 
I didn't know that there was a difference between "disconnect" and "disconnecting" that's why I didn't get the roomId on "disconnect".

Answer (score 0):

Recently troubled with the same problem.
The code below should be the answer to what you're looking for.  It may not be the most elegant solution, but works.

The catch is instead of using `socket.join("something")`
You need to use something like this `this.roomHandler.room(socket,"room1","join")`.

```
class myserver{
    constructor(){


        this.io = require('socket.io')(85);
        this.io.on('connection', (socket) => {

            console.log("New User")

            this.roomHandler.room(socket,"room1","join")
            this.roomHandler.room(socket,"room2","join")
            //this.roomHandler.room(socket,"room3","join")
            this.roomHandler.room(socket,"room3","leave")


            console.log("---")
            console.log(this.roomHandler.roomsOfUser)

            socket.on('disconnect', (reason) => {
                this.roomHandler.disconnect(socket, reason)
                console.log(this.roomHandler.roomsOfUser)
            })

        })




        //Room Event Handler Definition
        this.roomHandler = {
            disconnect:(socket, reason)=>{

                if(this.roomHandler.roomsOfUser[socket.id]){
                    this.roomHandler.roomsOfUser[socket.id].forEach(room => {
                        this.roomHandler.room(socket, room, "disconnect")
                    })
                    delete this.roomHandler.roomsOfUser[socket.id];
                }
            },

            roomEvents : {},
            roomsOfUser: {},

            room:(socket,room,action)=>{//Join Or Leave
                if(typeof socket == "object" && typeof socket.join == "function"){
                    if(typeof room=="string"){

                        //Room Join
                        if(action=="join"){
                            socket.join(room)
                            this.roomHandler.roomOn(room,"join",socket)

                            //Create, append room collection for user
                            if(this.roomHandler.roomsOfUser[socket.id]){
                                this.roomHandler.roomsOfUser[socket.id].push(room)
                            }else{
                                this.roomHandler.roomsOfUser[socket.id] = [room]
                            }


                        //Room Leave
                        }else if(action == "leave"){
                            if(this.roomHandler.roomsOfUser[socket.id][room]){//Really in the room?
                                socket.leave(room)
                                this.roomHandler.roomOn(room,"leave", socket)
                            }

                        //User Disconnected
                        }else if(action == "disconnect"){
                            this.roomHandler.roomOn(room,"leave", socket)

                        }else{
                            console.log("Undefined room action.")
                        }

                    }else{ console.log("Unqualified name for room."); }
                }else{ console.error("Not a legit socket object",socket); socket.join("aaa") }
            },

            roomOn:(room, event, socket)=>{
                if (typeof this.roomHandler.roomEvents[room] == "function"){
                    this.roomHandler.roomEvents[room](event,socket)
                }else{
                    console.log(`No event found for ${room}`, this.roomHandler.roomEvents)
                }
            },

            roomRegister:(room,callback)=>{
                if (typeof room == "string" && typeof callback == "function") {
                    console.log(`Callback registered for ${room}`)
                    this.roomHandler.roomEvents[room] = callback
                }else{
                    console.log("Room name or callback is invalid.")
                }
            }
        }
        //END OF HANDLER


        //Register Functions for room events.
        this.roomHandler.roomRegister("room1",(event,socket)=>{
            console.log(`${event} for room1 BY ${socket.id}`)
        })

        this.roomHandler.roomRegister("room2",(event,socket)=>{
            console.log(`${event} for room2 BY ${socket.id}`)
        })

        this.roomHandler.roomRegister("room3",(event,socket)=>{
            console.log(`${event} for room3 BY ${socket.id}`)
        })



    }

}



const server = new myserver();
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are outdated; there is a *much* simpler approach that doesn't require new events.

According to the docs (linked below), starting from `socket.io@3.1.0`, namespace adapters expose four room-related events. Two of them are useful to us right now, namely `join-room` and `leave-room`.

```js
// server.js

io.on("connection", function (socket) {
  // your main code here
});

io.of("/").adapter.on("join-room", function (room, id) {
  /* stuff */
});

io.of("/").adapter.on("leave-room", function (room, id) {
  /* stuff */
});
```

I highly suggest you [read the documentation](https://socket.io/docs/v4/rooms/#room-events) on this topic. It explains how rooms work behind the scenes and lists the events you can listen for.

<sup>Note: this answer was written when `socket.io@4.6.2` was the latest version.</sup>

Answer (score -5):

You can use the native "disconnect" event.

```
socket.on('disconnect', function () {

        io.sockets.emit('user disconnected');
    });
```

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. I want to create event handlers for when sockets `join()` and `leave()` rooms, not connect to or disconnect from the server completely (though disconnecting _should_ result in a `"leave"` event).

Comment: @camupod - sockets don't know about "rooms". Room is an application level concept, so a socket never joins or leaves a room. You'll have to write some higher level handlers to issue join and leave events yourself.

Comment: @StephenP - sockets don't need to know about rooms. I'm wondering if it's possible for a "room" (`io.sockets.in('name')`) to tell me when something joined or left.