# socket.io - handler parameters for join and leave room

Tags: socket.io

Follow up to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8392171/37759). In answer given, handler for `join` has no parameters.

```
room.on('join', function() {
  console.log("Someone joined the room.");
});
```

Is that correct? Handler for `join` doesn't have arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`join` is not a built-in event; it's a custom event that gets emitted a little later in the example. It can take arguments just like any other event in Socket.IO.

Comment: ahh. there isn't a built-in join/leave event. hasn't been implemented yet https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/420    :(