# How to customize socket.io's connection event by room?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

When a socket connects to a socket.io server, a `connection` event is triggered. The function that handles such event can be overrided to add custom behavior to the connection.

I want to add a function to handle the `connection` event, but for a socket.io room.

I was trying something like (with socket.io 0.9.14):

```
io.sockets.in('someNamespace/someRoom').on('connection', function () {
    //custom actions here
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. The behavior is attached to the default connection event and triggered on every connection.

Is it possible to achieve what I'm trying? any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't the sockets have to connect before they can join a room?

Comment: yes, but once they connect, I add them to specific rooms (e.g. socket.join('/someNamespace/someRoom')), so I want to trigger specific actions, depending on the room(s) the socket connected, by 'overriding' that room's `onConnect` event

Comment: I don't think there's such a thing as a `connect` event for rooms.  But [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391804/is-it-possible-to-listen-for-join-and-leave-events-on-a-room) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question clearly, you're trying to use namespaces. Then you should do it like this:

```
io.of('/someNamespace/someRoom').on('connection', function (socket) {
  //your actions here
});
```

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't seem to work for me. Indeed it is possible to attach logic to the `namespace`'s `connection` event, but it's like socket.io recognizes `/` separated `namespace` names as `rooms`, so the event isn't triggered. By the way, I'm using `join` to add the socket to the room: `socket.join('/someNamespace/someRoom')` could it be affecting? or maybe isn't possible to change the `connection` event for a particular room?

Comment: rooms and namespaces are different things, you can connect to a namespace using io.connect('http://localhost:port/somenamespace'). If you want to know more about rooms, see this https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to simulate a similar behavior (similar to the `on-connection` handler) for rooms, using the `callback` (or `fn`) argument for [the socket.io 0.9.14 join function](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/0.9.14/lib/socket.js#L164), like this:

```
socket.join('some/room', function handleJoin () {
    //do something when socket joins to 'some/room'
})
```

For the version `0.9.14` of `socket.io`, when the `join` function has a second argument, a [warning](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/0.9.14/lib/socket.js#L172) is displayed telling:

```
Client#join callback is deprecated
```

But for the [current one, in the master branch](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/81e8a0c3a5ace051e43bd4905343cf2a9ef1baac/lib/socket.js#L195) (version 1.0.0-pre), the warning is no longer there and the callback function can be used for error handling on room joining. So, it might be safe to rely on the existence of this argument in the future.

Finally, by using a wrapper function on the `join` call, it is possible to preserve the closure for the call, thus providing the same arguments that an `on connection` handler normally takes.

e.g. (in some place inside the server)

```
var someVar = 'some value';
socket.join('some/room', function () {
    handleJoin(someVar);
});
```

And then, `somevar` will be available inside the `handleJoin` function (`somevar` could be the `room` name, for example). Of course, it is a very simple example and it could be adapted to meet different requirements or to comply with the upcoming version of the `join` function.

Hope this helps.