# Create a private room in socket io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I have a node js server witch is for a chat page. Now I want to make a private messiging part of the server. Currently i have the following code:
Client:

```
    rooms.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(roomName.value){
          socket.emit('Join-Room', roomName.value);
          roomName.value = '';
        }
      });
```

Server:

```
socket.on('Join-Room', (roomName) => {
    socket.join(roomName);
  });
```

When I try to join one room nothing happens and i am still in the main chat.

Comment: What happens if you `console.log(...)`  inside the `.on('Join-Room',(...))` and inside your `if`?

Comment: if i console.log(roomname) it displays the room i wish to join. But for some reason i dont join the room

Comment: Does [this help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391804)? Be sure to read all of the answers, because some of them are more recent, and might be more relevant.